# Using const with arrow function returning component vs just the component in render()

Tags: reactjs

Is there any difference whatsoever if rendering the main component in the index.jsx of a React app like this:

```
import { App } from './App';
const root = document.getElementById('my-app');

const Program = () => {
    return <App />;
};

render(<Program />, root);
```

vs

```
import { App } from './App';
const root = document.getElementById('my-app');

render(<App />, root);
```

And is there ever a case to use the first option?

Comment: The structural difference is that the former introduces another layer of component.  When you test, is there any observed difference?  Does the resulting markup change in any way?

Comment: It seems identical to me when I try both. Is there ever a use case for adding another layer of component?

Comment: I imagine such a use case would be on a case-by-case basis.  In the example shown I can't think of a reason.  In a larger application it could act as a placeholder or general top-level component for potential future logic.  Usually `<App>` serves that purpose.

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

```
import { App } from './App';
const root = document.getElementById('my-app');

const Program = () => {
    return <App />;
};

const LayerTwo = () => {
  return <Program />
};


render(<LayerTwo />, root);
```

This will also return the same component, but yet another layer. Because of [KIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) (keep it simple) the first option you mention should be avoided and the second option is the best:

```
import { App } from './App';
const root = document.getElementById('my-app');

render(<App />, root);
```